# Strategy for minimizing java ee heap usage

Tags: java, mysql, dictionary, heap-memory

I am building an application for translating E books. I have dictionary files which are .csv files that I fill into java hash map. The dictionaries are up to 150 mb large .The problem I am coming to is that for this to work right in localhost I need to increase java heap size to 512 mb - for one user myself this works fine . I do not know how this will behave when there are a lot of users using the application .So I am using to much heap.I tried to move my dictionaries into mysql database - but now for every word(could be up to 150 000 single words by ebook) I am hitting the database - this reduces the heap usage but,Again if I have more users using the application at the same time it would be bad.I was thinking to parse e book twice first time to put all the words into java set - get only the unique words that are in the e book and only put those words into hash map dictionary, or to call mysql for more than one word at the time(use sql "in" operator) . Since java hosting is priced by heap usage could you give me an alternative approach that could minimize the heap size usage for my use case.
This is the way I am using mysql database:

```
public final class ConnectionStrings {


       private String USERNAME="root";
       private String PASSWORD="";
       private  String CONN_STRING="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dictionary?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"; 


       public ConnectionStrings() 
       {

       }
       public String getUsername()
       {        return this.USERNAME;
       }

        public String getPassword()
       {        return this.PASSWORD;
       }

          public String getConnString()
       {        return this.CONN_STRING;
       }





}
```

and this is the method that takes the data from mysql

```
public static String getMySQlTranslation(String word, String combination) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    ConnectionStrings c = new ConnectionStrings();
    String CONN_STRING = c.getConnString();
    String USERNAME = c.getUsername();
    String PASSWORD = c.getPassword();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    String returnedWord = "-";

    String upit = "select translated_word from dictionary where native_word = ? and combination= ? limit 1";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(upit);
    stmt.setString(1, word);
    stmt.setString(2, combination);

    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        returnedWord = rs.getString("translated_word");

    }

    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();

    return returnedWord;
}//
```

This is the way the method is called in code

```
translated_word=Translator.getMySQlTranslation(check, description);
```

Comment: You're saying a lot of "it would be bad" things, even though you have no idea if it would be bad or not. One obvious mistake in your question is that you're acting like each user would have their own hashmap, instead of using a shared one. Database would be also a far better choice than loading CSV files to memory.

Comment: I have a method for testing that uses mysql and it works 10 times slower to produce the translated document . If you have 150 000 calls to mysql database for every document that is translated , this must be bad right !? So imagine that there are 10 users generating a translated book from mysql at the same time - this is what I was thing on , mysql could not take it.The translation is done in a loop where text is split by space and words are looked up in a dictionary .

Comment: MySQL can easily take it, you've probably just written inefficient code. Are your indexes fine? Do you have properly configured connection pool?

Comment: I have the index set on the word , the words are unique . The query is like this "select translated_word from dictionary where native_word = ? and combination= ? limit 1" with the index set on native_word ...So what you are proposing is that it is best to use mysql...I do a call for every word...

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Or rather, are you using Connections efficiently?

Comment: I will edit the question...

Comment: And there's your problem. Creating a database connection is very expensive, and your code is doing that for every single word. It's not MySQL's fault that it's slow, it's yours.

Comment: I will change this and see how it goes ...

Comment: Don't just do something and see what happens. It didn't work for you to begin with. Learn to work with JDBC efficiently.

Comment: Except for doing this changes on the mysql is there an alternative approach here , use something else...

Comment: Well you can stick to your original plan of using a HashMap. At least the lookups will be fast and you have less chance of doing something inefficient.